# Running scripts on source upload

Tags: php, scripting, netbeans-6.9, uploading

I'm using Netbeans 6.9 to develop PHP code; testing happens locally on my PC (XAMPP); once done code is uploaded using Netbeans upload facility to the production web server.

I recall reading about Netbeans capabilities running scripts when "building" the project, and looking for a primer about it.
Particularly I'm looking for some ways to achieve the following, right before uploading files to the production server:
- strip comments from PHP sources
- minify PHP
- minify Javascript & CSS

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: I have just the same question...

Comment: Ha-ha, searching for the answer around the internet finds your posts on various forums... unfortunately, without an answer...

Comment: Yeah, normally Netbeans uses Ant to build its projects. But it doesn't seem to do that for PHP projects. In any case what's the reason for wanting to clean up the PHP code?

Comment: CurtainDog, for example to remove comments, minify code and so on..

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may be aiming for is a tool like Apache Ant. It runs an XML with several targets which usually are nothing more than some shell scripts.

So this means;

- Setup Apache Ant
- Find some CLI/shell scripts to do the jobs you mention
- Create an ANT build file with the FTP upload in the end
- Run the ANT file

More info on Apache Ant; http://ant.apache.org/